# Which hardware supports eyes and mouth detection?

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm developing an Android app that can be specified to run only on a specific hardware (not worried about working on every device); and this app will have some face recognition features and I was hoping to use `leftEye`, `rightEye` and `mouth` fields from the `android.hardware.Camera.Face` class.

I know that those fields, as per docs are optional (`This is an optional field, may not be supported on all devices.`); but I've tested on a Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, nexus 7 and Nexus 10 and none of those supported those features.

So my question: is there any hardware out the that does actually work with those fields?

Comment: how can this be harware related ?

Comment: because it's an optional feature available in the platform that is only implemented on devices where the camera hardware accepts is capable of doing it.

Comment: i still don't see what it has to do with the camera hardware.

Comment: it's just like WiFi-Direct. All devices have WiFi but not all of them have WiFi Direct. => All devices have camera, most have face detection, and I can't find one that does have facial features detection.

Comment: i'm pretty sure face detection is not in the camera hardware, but rather in how you implement the recognition. it's not like wifi direct, because a camera is much dumber than a wifi chip. wifi direct requires instructions in the chip, while face detection is pure higher-lever software.

Comment: please refere to page 19 of this doc (https://marakana.com/s/post/1268/Exposing_the_Android_Camera_Stack.pdf) Face detection is a hardware accelerated feature contained in the hardware abstraction layer and it's manufacturer dependant.

Comment: the doc (not to mention I have no idea where it comes from and cannot assess its reliability), hardly mentions that the Camera HAL is hardware dependant. It doesn't mention hardware acceleration for face detection. (although it is likely some computations required for face detection can be accelerated by the GPU for instance)

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung GT-I9300 can detect the eyes, but can't detect mouth.

Comment: is that the Galaxy S3? Do you know that by code-testing or are you just saying it because it does have the eye track functionalities?

Comment: I'm developing a face-detection app on Samsung Galaxy S3. It worked very well in Android 4.0.4, and I was able to detect faces and eyes. But this morning I update the firmware and now it doesn't work anymore (I can detect faces, but I can't detect eyes)!